# What is the best way to implement ajax based pagination on custom query based templates?

Tags: pagination, ajax

We can use multiple plugins like wp-pagenavi or wp-paginate for implementing pagination for wordpress sites and making it ajax based using the following code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    // ajax pagination
    jQuery('#wp_page_numbers a').live('click', function(){ 

        var link = jQuery(this).attr('href');                   
        jQuery('#main').html('Loading'); 
        jQuery('#main').load(link+' #entries')
    });
}); // end ready function
```

Sometimes, there are some cases where we want to display results based on custom query (i.e fetching results from the tables other than wordpress default tables) on a page template.

What is the best way for implementing pagination in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Soumitra Chakraborty wrote a very good tutorial on [Getting Started with AJAX & WordPress Pagination](http://wp.tutsplus.com/articles/getting-started-with-ajax-wordpress-pagination/).  I would recommend following that pattern (in terms of how to use [`admin_ajax.php`](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) in conjunction with your `functions.php`.

That tutorial will give you a great framework for how to implement ajax pagination by hand.

In terms of your own specific requirements for a custom query (which it sounds like might involve getting data from non-standard tables) you can use the [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) class to do some pretty advanced stuff (like what you describe) in your custom function that you define in `functions.php`.

Comment: Thanks for providing this article Jared. I'll try to implement ajax using these steps now.

Answer (score 0):

I have just find a simple solution where I have tried several "advanced" and modern frameworks, but old reliable jquery make it simple.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// ajax pagination

$('#paginator a').on('click', function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('paginate');
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    $('.current').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
    $('#main-content').html('Loading');

    $('#blog').load(link+' #main-content');
    $('#paginator').load(link+' .pagination') 
});
```

});

I just add some minor variations in order to update the post grid, in my case main content. and pagination status in my case #pagination. Both with an inner div to just update what is being modified.